# JDBC + PL/SQL = Is it so simple, or is there a catch?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am planning to execute Oracle PL\SQL blocks via JDBC (can't test it yet, question of few days). Is there anything I should know? Does everything work as it used to with plain SQL?

I mean:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("DECLARE BEGIN NULL; END;");
```

Or will I need some custom classes? I'd like to keep it as much simple as possible (no ORM etc.).

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to call PL/SQL anonymous blocks using a standard `CallableStatement` (and Oracle JDBC drivers of course). See [Returning data from anonymous PL/SQL block](http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/10/returning-data-from-anonymous-plsql.html) for some example code.

#### See also

- Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference

  - [Stored Procedure Calls in JDBC Programs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/basic.htm#i1008346)