# Using cursors and getting result in Oracle PL/SQL with Java/JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a PL/SQL query constructed like this :

```
DECLARE
a NUMBER;
B NUMBER;
CURSOR cursor
IS
 ( SOME SELECT QUERY);
BEGIN
  OPEN cursor;
    LOOP
    SOME STUFF;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor;
END
```

How can I run this query from a java code using jdbc and get the resultset? I have tried running the query without using cursor, and its running correctly. I couldn't figure out a way to do this in java code. If I run the query directly onto oracle client, it works with no problems. So there is no problem with the query.

P.S. I dont want to store the code as stored procedure and call that due to some constraints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot return a result set from an anonymous PL/SQL block (and therefor there is no way to get it from JDBC).

You will need to run the select directly from JDBC.

The only, really ugly workaround would be to use `dbms_output.put_line()` and the read that afterwards. But that is a really ugly hack and processing the result of the SELECT query directly in JDBC is much better.

---

### Edit 1

Here is a little example using dbms_output:

```
Connection con = ....;

// turn on support for dbms_output
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbms_output.enable(32000) }");
cstmt.execute();

// run your PL/SQL block
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql =
    "declare  \n" +
    " a number;  \n" +
    " cursor c1 is select id from foo;  \n" +
    "begin  \n" +
    "  open c1; \n" +
    "  loop \n" +
    "    fetch c1 into a;  \n" +
    "    exit when c1%notfound;  \n" +
    "    dbms_output.put_line('ID: '||to_char(a)); \n" +
    "  end loop; \n" +
    "end;";
stmt.execute(sql);

// retrieve the messages written with dbms_output
cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbms_output.get_line(?,?)}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

int status = 0;
while (status == 0)
{
    cstmt.execute();
    String line = cstmt.getString(1);
    status = cstmt.getInt(2);
    if (line != null && status == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 2 (this is too long for a comment)

Nesting loops to retrieve data is almost always a bad idea. If you find your self doing something like this:

```
begin
  for data_1 in (select id from foo_1) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(data_1.id));

    for data_2 in (select f2.col1, f2.col2 from foo_2 f2 where f2.id = data_1.id) loop
        ... do something else
    end loop;

  end loop;
end;
/
```

It will be a lot more efficient to do it like this:

```
begin
  for data_1 in (select f2.col1, f2.col2 from foo_2 f2
                 where f2.id in (select f1.id from foo_1 f1)) loop

     ... do something

  end loop;
end;
/
```

This can be processed without an excessive memory in JDBC using something like this:

```
String sql = "select f2.col1, f2.col2 from foo_2 f2 where f2.id in (select f1.id from foo_1 f1)";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next())
{
   String col1_value = rs.getString(1);
   int    col2_value = rs.getInt(2);
   ... do something
}
```

The above code will only hold one row in memory, even if you process billions of rows. To be precise: the JDBC driver will actually pre-fetch more than one row. The default is 10 and can be changed. But even then you don't have any excessive memory usage.

Comment: Is there a way to return string from PL/SQL block to java program? Or the only option left is to process the same in java program itself?

Comment: I have already tried using dbms_output.put_line(). It didn't work and throws invalid sql (same exception without that too).
Using PL/SQL is required as I am running a query in that block too, using every row from the cursor. Loading the entire first result and unning that query from this many times from java code will be slower, no? (I don't know.)

Comment: @RajatGarg: I added an example on how to use `dbms_output()`. But I would very much question the fact that "*PL/SQL is required*". This is a very stupid requirement for such a simple task, makes processing the result pretty complicated and will in general be a lot slower than processing the result of a query directly.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will try to explain the scenario. I am retrieving a cursor by the select query. Then I need to use every row of that resultset(cursor), to query another table using some predicates. Alternate can be, I get the resultset in java, for every row i query the second table. But that will take resources on my JVM, and will use huge memory. With PLSQL block, I am delegating this processing to db server so I get the processed minimal results and use less memory.

Comment: @RajatGarg: Running a select inside a loop is almost always a bad idea. In nearly all of the cases you can replace that with a single SQL statement. If you process the ResultSet row by row, then you do **not** load the data completely into memory, so it would not take "huge memory in the JVM". And if you are processing so many rows, then the buffer for `dbms_output` will probably be too small anyway to handle all that. You should post your *real* problem (a select inside a loop over another select) to get help on that. You are fighting symptons, not the real problem.

Comment: Agreeing with @a_horse_with_no_name ... the answer is to use a single SQL statement. That is so often the case that it needs a snappy acronym .. JOSS? ("Just One SQL Statement")

Comment: Thanks Guys. @a_horse_with_no_name your solution is correct and will work for me with some alteration of course. I surely agree on you guys on JOSS thing, even I tried a lot for the same. I can't post exact problem here, but trust me it was really not possible to get it done with a single select. The select inside loop use some aggregate functions and aggregation is not just a group by thing, but depends on more conditions. I admit that might be too much logic for a PLSQL and should ideally go in java code, but things are sometimes like this. Well thanks a lot.

Comment: @RajatGarg: you do know how to use analytical functions and common table expressions (aka "sub-query factoring")?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, I don't know that much. Can you point me to some location for a read up for beginners?

Comment: This answer is wrong. `SYS_REFCURSOR` types could be fetched as `OUT` parameters for quite a while and since Oracle 12c, we can use [`DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` as I've illustrated in a recent blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/02/08/how-to-fetch-oracle-12c-implicit-cursors-with-jdbc-and-jooq/). The `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` approach is certainly not the way to go here :-)

Answer (score 7):

@Rajat,

Could you try below method:

To retrieve the cursor you should declare it as a REF CURSOR in Package spec.

```
  --Creating the REF CURSOR type
  type g_cursor is ref cursor;
```

In both, spec and body, you need declare an out REF CURSOR variable in procedure signature, how cited above.

```
  procedure PRO_RETURN_CARS(
    i_id     in     tbl_car.car_id%type,
    o_cursor in out g_cursor);
```

The cursor must be opened in procedure’s body to return, this way:

```
open o_cursor for
          select car_id, company, model, color, hp, price
          from tbl_car
          where car_id = i_id;
```

The complete Package:

```
create or replace package PAC_CURSOR is
  --Creating REF CURSOR type
  type g_cursor is ref cursor;

  --Procedure that return the cursor
  procedure PRO_RETURN_CARS(
    i_id     in     tbl_car.car_id%type,
    o_cursor in out g_cursor); -- Our cursor

end PAC_CURSOR;
/

create or replace package body PAC_CURSOR is
  procedure PRO_RETURN_CARS(
    i_id     in     tbl_car.car_id%type,
    o_cursor in out g_cursor) is

       begin
        --Opening the cursor to return matched rows
        open o_cursor for
          select car_id, company, model, color, hp, price
          from tbl_car
          where car_id = i_id;

  end PRO_RETURN_CARS;

end PAC_CURSOR;
```

We have Oracle side ready, now we need create Java call

How the cursors are being returned by a procedure, we’ll used a `java.sql.CallableStatement` instance:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call PAC_CURSOR.PRO_RETURN_CARS(?,?)}");
```

The `registerOutParameter` will obtain `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR` type and return a `java.sql.ResultSet` instance. We can iterate the `ResultSet` like a common `Iterator`.

Each row column returned by SELECT will be represented how a map, using correspondent getter. For example, we will call getString() method when value of column is a varchar, getDate() when is a date and etc.

The complete code will be like this:

```
//Calling Oracle procedure
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call PAC_CURSOR.PRO_RETURN_CARS(?,?)}");

//Defining type of return
cs.registerOutParameter("o_cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.setLong("i_id", id);

cs.execute();//Running the call

//Retrieving the cursor as ResultSet
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject("o_cursor");

//Iterating the returned rows
while(rs.next()){
    //Getting column values
    System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getLong("car_id"));
    System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + rs.getString("company"));
    System.out.println("Model: " + rs.getString("model"));
    System.out.println("Color: " + rs.getString("color"));
    System.out.println("HP: " + rs.getString("hp"));
    System.out.println("Price: " + rs.getFloat("price"));
}
```

In the end you will get any value returned in a SELECT clause.

Comment: Can I use your solution with returning cursor with operation  
DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur);

And what about closing the cursor on your case. Because when returned cursor with "Out" parameter keyword in Procedure, Is It automatically closed after finishing execution of PRO_RETURN_CARS Procedure ?

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here seem super complicated.

#### Using `SYS_REFCURSOR`

Since forever, you could retrieve `SYS_REFCURSOR` types very easily from JDBC:

```sql
DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR SELECT ...;
  ? := cur;
END;
```

Now run the above from Java like this:

```java
try (CallableStatement c = con.prepareCall(sql)) {
    c.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); // -10
    c.execute();

    try (ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) c.getObject(1)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also declare your own cursors in packages as suggested by [pmr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20650560/521799), but why would you if you're running an anonymous block from JDBC?

#### Using Oracle 12c implicit result sets

Oracle 12c added a handy new feature for these cases, which resembles the way SQL Server / Sybase and MySQL think about procedures / batches that return results. You can now use the [`DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS73893) procedure on any cursor, which returns it "by magic":

```sql
DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR SELECT ...;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur);
END;
```

[Due to a bug (or "feature") in the Oracle JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42091653/521799), it's a bit more tricky to fetch that cursor correctly from JDBC [but it can certainly be done as I've shown in this article here](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-fetch-oracle-12c-implicit-cursors-with-jdbc-and-jooq/). This is how you can discover any number of implicit cursors from any anonymous PL/SQL block and/or procedure, trigger, etc...:

```java
try (PreparedStatement s = cn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    // Use good old three-valued boolean logic
    Boolean result = s.execute();

    fetchLoop:
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {

        // Check for more results if not already done in this iteration
        if (i > 0 && result == null)
            result = s.getMoreResults();
        System.out.println(result);

        if (result) {
            result = null;

            try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
                System.out.println("Fetching result " + i);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                // Ignore ORA-17283: No resultset available
                if (e.getErrorCode() == 17283)
                    continue fetchLoop;
                else
                    throw e;
            }
        }
        else if (s.getUpdateCount() == -1)
            // Ignore -1 value if there is one more result!
            if (result = s.getMoreResults())
                continue fetchLoop;
            else
                break fetchLoop;
    }
}
```

#### Using jOOQ

In case you're using jOOQ already in your application to call stored procedures, you could avoid the above JDBC loop and use `DSLContext.fetchMany()` in order to easily fetch all the cursors into one data structure:

```java
for (Result<?> result : ctx.fetchMany(sql))
  for (Record record : result)
    System.out.println(record);
```

Or, use [code generation in case this is from a procedure](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/), instead of an anonymous block. Your procedure will then give access to these results using `procedure.getResults()`

Comment: You explained the Using Oracle 12c implicit result sets and a handy new feature 
  OPEN cur FOR SELECT ...;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur);



Can I use this feature and to read the data in java 
try (CallableStatement c = con.prepareCall(sql)) {
    c.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); // -10
    c.execute();

    try (ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) c.getObject(1)) {
        ...
    }
}  in this way. 
Why am I asking because I was not able to understand second part of your code with 
fetchLoop:

Comment: Is second part for debugging purpose ?

Comment: @RahimjonRustamov: My example code here works out of the box, and you can use it by adapting it as you need. Only the println commands are used for debugging. You'll replace them by actually consuming your result set. The rest is required as it is, as I have described. I don't think you can use a `CallableStatement` like you did. But anyway, ideally, you'll ask a new, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the signature of java.sql.PreparedStatement.execute() is "boolean execute()" not "Boolean execute()", "result" variable could never be null as the consequence of boxing the returned value of the s.execute(), so the test "i>0 && result==null" could be "result==null"