# Select for update skip locked with row limit

Tags: java, oracle, queue, batch-processing

I have a program written in Java that creates 5 threads which select data from Oracle.
The select is like this:

```
select * from queue_requests where request_status = 0 and date_requested <= sysdate and rownum <= ? for update skip locked
```

I set the parameter to 1024. I often get the following result (using System.out.println):

> THREAD 0 UPDATE 1024
>
> THREAD 4 UPDATE 0
>
> THREAD 1 UPDATE 0
>
> THREAD 2 UPDATE 0
>
> THREAD 3 UPDATE 0

So, only one thread finds rows to update.
From what i found in different articles, i think oracle firstly applies the **rownum** clause and after that **for update skip locked**, so all the threads try to update the first 1024 rows.
I could probably use something like:

```
select * from (select * from queue_requests where request_status = 0 and date_requested <= sysdate for update skip locked) where rownum <= ?
```

But this will lock all the rows and after that will return a part of them. I don't want to lock all the rows.

I found a solution which created stored procedures, but i can't alter anything in the database. I also found something about Advanced Queueing, but i'm not sure i need something so complex (i didn't find any good example either).

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: SKIP LOCKED is intended queue processing i.e. get the next unlocked thing in the queue. So the idea is to take just one thing from the top of the stack. Grabbing a slack handful every time suggests you have not designed your queues correctly.  I know FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED allows us to select more than one row, I just think we shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want each thread to only select about one fifth of the records, you might do something like:

```
select *
from   queue_requests
where  request_status = 0 and
       date_requested <= sysdate and
       mod(DBMS_RowID.RowID_Row_Number(queue_requests.rowid),5) = thread_number
       rownum <= ?
for update
skip locked;
```

... where thread_number is an integer between 0 and 4.

The success of this depends on the likely number of rows per block for the queue_requests table. If the rows are small then you'll be OK, but if they're large and you have many rows then you might do better with:

```
mod(DBMS_RowID.RowID_Block_Number(queue_requests.rowid),5)
```

Comment: Could you explain why the number or rows per block matters?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could not altern your db you could execute a block of PL/SQL to have the "working" implementation with cursors: [Execute anonymous pl/sql block and get resultset in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java)