# How to execute an Oracle PLSQL block in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have an PL/SQL block like this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..100
  LOOP
    UPDATE rptbody 
       SET comments = 'abcs';
     WHERE (rptno> 100 and rptno < 200) and ROWNUM<2;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This block needs to be executed using Oracle JDBC. I have tried the following methods:

- Tried to execute this using Statement object. Since this is a block, an exception was raised saying that this is not an sql statement
- This can be split up into sql statements, but I have 100s of such blocks which would be cumbersome for the code and thought of leaving this to the sqlplus.
- Tried with CallableStatement which did not work as well.

Any solutions would be helpful.

Comment: You are right in your point, this is an anonymous PL/SQL block not SQL

Comment: Can you post the Java code you're using (particularly for the `CallableStatement` version)?  And post the exact error stack you're getting.

Comment: In conjunction with what Justin mentioned, you might find this helpful to get the errors fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10465239/350136

Comment: You _can_ run this through a `Statement` object, you have to use `Statement.execute()` though. You only need a `CallableStatement` if oyu need to pass parameters to the PL/SQL block. And you need to post your Java code. "did not work" is neither an acceptable error description nor a valid Java or Oracle exception

Comment: Btw: I just hope your example is not the real code you are running, because that can be achieved **much** more efficiently without a PL/SQL block using a single statement - rather than the slow-by-slow approach through a cursor.

Comment: See http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2006/10/slow-by-slow.html to get what a_horse_with_no_name is getting at.

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with how you run it. The PL/SQL syntax is invalid. You have a `;` after the update clause right before the `WHERE` clause:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..100
  LOOP
    UPDATE rptbody 
       SET comments = 'abcs' --<<< no semicolon here!!
     WHERE (rptno> 100 and rptno < 200) and ROWNUM<2;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The above code can be run like this:

```
String sql = "... the PL/SQL block ...";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out some code samples to use CallableStatement and PreparedStatement on [Github](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples)

Answer (score 0):

*Tried to execute this using Statement object. Since this is a block, an exception was raised saying that this is not an sql statement*

```
Since you were trying to execute a plsql block, you should not use Statement object.
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html:
   The object used for executing a **static SQL statement** and returning the results it produces.

This is the way you need to execute a block:

```
CallableStatement anonBlock = null // Note that CallableStatement is an interface

String anonBlockString = '' //Generally multi line
// Set in and out parameters as needed by your anonBlockString

anonBlock.registerOutParameter( <number> , <type> )

...

// executeUpdate() is inherited from PreparedStatement and can be used for executing DML statements (update, insert, delete)
anonBlock.executeUpdate(); 


To access out parameters:
anonBlock.getString(<number which you have assigned in registerOutParameter() calls);
```

For complete example: (https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/timesten/1121/quickstart/sample_code/jdbc/plsqlJDBC.java)

*This can be split up into sql statements, but I have **100s of such blocks** which would be cumbersome for the code and thought of leaving this to the sqlplus.*

Prefer to use stored procedures instead of anonymous blocks. Since **stored procedures are stored in a compiled and optimized format**, they have a **performance boost** compared to anonymous ones

*Tried with CallableStatement which did not work as well:*

What was the code, error/stack?