# Oracle Merge Sql with insert in destination and delete from source

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a Scenario where i have 2 Tables 1st is source(my_data) and 2nd is destination(my_data_backup),I want to **some kind of archiving** of actual data and move that data into backup table on the daily basis and delete from source table **using Merge SQL in oracle**.

i.e.

my_data and my_data_backup  **both have same schema**

**my_data table contains  10 rows and my_data_backup contains 0 rows i want to insert 10 records into my_data_backup and delete those records from my_data.**

Comment: Lets say on second run, you have 5 more rows my_data. Now should backup contain 15 rows and my_data should be empty again? Also what is the key in backup table? Are you sure the key is not coming again from `my_data` again?

Comment: yes, correct there is no duplicacy in both, At the end of day i will move data from my_data to my_data_backup.

Comment: What data volumes are you talking about here?

Comment: @BobC- around 1000 rows per day in a table, i want to move them from my_data to my_data_backup and remove those rows from my_data at the EOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MERGE` is useful to do manipulation on the destination table, not source.

You can use an anonymous PLSQL block:

```
begin
    delete from my_data_backup;
    insert into my_data_backup
    select *
    from my_data;
    delete from my_data;
    commit;
exception
    when others then
        rollback;
        -- handle here
end;
/
```

You can also put the above in a procedure and call the procedure.

You can think about using truncate statement instead of delete which will be faster when the table size is larger but be careful that it, being a DDL, will do an implicit commit.

```
execute immediate 'truncate table tablename';
```

Comment: I don't want to create it using stored procedure Using Oracle Merge SQL i want this,could you please help me out from this situation

Comment: @NikhiK.Bansal - The above is **not** a stored procedure, It's an anonymous block

Comment: @Gurv- Can i run this from java code or i have to put this block of queries to somewhere in datbase.

Comment: I'd suggest you to create a procedure in that case, but here is one solution without it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java

Comment: Ok, let me try your solution with anonymous block, well this is possible or not using Merge SQL.

Comment: @Nikhil - You might think you can call the statements one by one from java. Problem in that is what if there are new rows inserted between insert and delete call.

Comment: @Gurv- i don't want to call them by separately, that's why i am asking about Oracle Merge SQL.  because i have done this by procedure 
i.e

create or replace
procedure sp_arch_at_logs(days_to_arch IN number DEFAULT 5)
AS
  no number(6) :=0 
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('START - SP_ARCH_AT_LOGS ');
  
    insert into my_data_backup select * from  FROM my_data;
 Delete from my_data; 
    
    COMMIT  ; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END - SP_ARCH_AT_LOGS ');
end;
/