# SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement using Java

Tags: java

I need to use following via Java `EXEC DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.SET_TAG(tag => HEXTORAW('17'));`  using a simple Database client.  along with other usual select/delete queries but its complaining for invalid SQL statement.

I tried removing the exec as its for PL/SQL and calling it with {} but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure in Java?  Please include the code you have.

Comment: DBClient.execute("exec DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.set_tag(tag => HEXTORAW('17'))");

Comment: `EXEC` is SQL*Plus syntax and you can't use it here. You could use an [anonymous PL/SQL block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java) or the `CALL` syntax instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXEC` is SQL*Plus (Oracle's native SQL client) syntax and you can't use it here. The JDBC syntax for calling stored procedures is through the `CALL` directive. You can omit the parameter name in the call (`tag => HEXTORAW('17')`). For example:

```
try (CallableStatement cs 
        = myConnection.prepareCall("{ call DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.SET_TAG(HEXTORAW(?)) }")) {

    cs.setString(1, "17");        
    cs.execute();
}
```

It is unclear which `DBClient` you are currently using (please tell us), but the following might work as well:

```
DBClient.execute("{ call DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.set_tag(HEXTORAW('17')) }");
```

or then

```
DBClient.execute("begin DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.SET_TAG(HEXTORAW('17')); end;");
```

Comment: I tried   DBClient.execute("{ call DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.set_tag(tag => HEXTORAW('17')) }");   but its complaning for    DBMS_STREAMS_ADM must be declared

Comment: It works out now.  Some user permission issue at the end. Thanks