# How to execute an anonymous plsql block with out parameters in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, plsql

How to execute an anonymous plsql block with out parameters in hibernate?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

//Example (as I would like):
Query q = session.createQuery("begin select user_name into :p_name from fnd_user where user_id = :p_id; end;");
q.registerParameter("p_name", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
q.registerParameter("p_id", String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(100);
q.execute();
```

But in Query there is no registration of parameters.

Existing methods with parameter registration are not suitable:

- `createNamedStoredProcedureQuery`
- `createStoredProcedureQuery`
- `createStoredProcedureCall`

add code to execute the procedure (`begin %ORIGINAL_SQL%(%PARAMS%); end;`).

P. S.: Vanilla option is working fine:

```
String name = session.doReturningWork((Connection c) -> {
  String sql = "declare v_str VARCHAR2(100); begin select user_name into :p_name 
  from fnd_user where user_id = :p_id; end;";
  CallableStatement cs = c.prepareCall(sql);
  cs.registerOutParameter("p_name", Types.VARCHAR);
  cs.setInt("p_id", 1);
  cs.execute();
  return cs.getString("p_name");
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should only call a stored procedure from db as "separation of concern" suggests and pass your parameters to that procedure. Not trying to build a query in your java code ?

Comment: @ismetguzelgun, the example is simplified, and can be a stored procedure. But me need exactly an `anonymous plsql block`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java did you check this before ? It is not using hibernate but vanilla java can also give you an idea ?

Comment: @ismetguzelgun, Vanilla java is working fine (added P.S.). I can’t believe that there is no solution in the Hibernate.

Comment: In 2020 If you can not find any solution for your case on stackoverflow there are mainly two reasons. First your problem is so simple that nobody ever need to ask it and second your case is so overly complicated that you should design it again with much care. I am no Java expert but I think your case better suits second reason.