# Is it possible to use Oracle Anonymous Block within the @Query annotation of Spring Data JPA Repository?

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an Emp table and associated JPA Entity - Employee. Emp table has id, name, and is_active columns.
Also there is an Assets table which has FK reference to Emp table. Assets table has id, emp_id, and name.

I would like to soft delete (update is_active='N') the employee but delete the assets associated using a repository method that reads

```
public interface EmployeeRepository implements JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
    @Query(
       nativeQuery = true,
       value="BEGIN"+
             "   delete from assets where emp_id = :employeeId;"+
             "   update emp set is_active= 'N' where id = :employeeId;" +
             "END" 
    )
    public void inactivate(@Param("employeeId") Long employeeId);
}
```

The above example is for illustrative purpose. When I try similar approach on my application's entities I am getting errors from Hibernate classes.

PS: I know that there are other approaches like Hibernates's cascade feature etc, but I am specifically interested in the use of Oracle Anonymous Blocks usage.

Comment: May you like something like this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101529/execute-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-get-resultset-in-java

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30... Thanks for the link... but I was exploring specifically for making it work via Spring Data JPA repository approach. I knew that we could achieve the same through JDBC CallableStatement, but I'd rather not write the JDBC code if I could achieve it via the Query (or some other) annotation.

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on spring boot starter data jpa 1.2.5 (hibernate 4.3.10), oracle 12c.

**Not work:**

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "begin insert into T (ID,A) values (:id, :a); exception when dup_val_on_index then update T set A = :a where ID = :id; end;", nativeQuery = true)
void upsertWatchdog(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("a") Date a);
```

Or:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "begin insert into T (ID,A) values (?1, ?2); exception when dup_val_on_index then update T set A = ?2 where ID = ?1; end;", nativeQuery = true)
void upsertWatchdog(Long id, Date a);
```

**Works:**

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "begin insert into T (ID,A) values (?1, ?2); exception when dup_val_on_index then update T set A = ?2 where ID = ?1 ; end;", nativeQuery = true)
void upsertWatchdog(Long id, Date a);
```

Or:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "begin insert into T (ID,A) values (:id, :a); exception when dup_val_on_index then update T set A = :a where ID = :id ; end;", nativeQuery = true)
void upsertWatchdog(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("a") Date a);
```

Or:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "begin insert into T (ID,A) values (?, ?); exception when dup_val_on_index then update T set A = ? where ID = ?; end;", nativeQuery = true)
void upsertWatchdog(Long id, Date a, Long id2, Date a2);
```

The crucial part is to use space between named/positioned params and semicolon, because hibernate considers named/positioned param name as *id;* instead of *id*.

But I am not sure whether it works because it is a feature or because it is a bug ;-)