# JPA Interface extending JpaRepository only, with use of EntityManager in default methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

First of all, for those who wanted to know how to use an EntityManager in an interface extending a JpaRepository.
Here is a potential solution.
But !!! I'm aware this is maybe a baaaad practice, and experienced people in Spring and JPA will maybe try to kill me ;) apologizes...

So, after this BIG warning, here is my question :

I would like to use only interfaces without a Custom implementation and this is what I did :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface BookingDao extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {

    Booking findByCodeId(String codeId);

    void deleteByCodeId(String codeId);

    default Integer findCountOfBookingOldDay() {
        EntityManager entityManager = ApplicationContextProvider.getEntityManager();
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("XXXX");
        Number result = (Number) query.getSingleResult();
        return result.intValue();
    }
}
```

```
    @Component(value = "applicationContextProvider")
    public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
        private static ApplicationContext context;
        public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            return context;
        }
        public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(context.getBean(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class).getObject());
            return context.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        }
        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
            context = ac;
        }
}
```

I'm aware this is maybe not the best practice, and the best way would be to use @PersistenceContext (takes care to create a unique EntityManager for every thread) in a class... But what would be in my case the best alternative :

this :

```
return EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(context.getBean(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class).getObject());
```

or this :

```
return context.getBean(EntityManager.class)
```

or maybe another better way, still by using only interface.

Thank you for your remarks/advices.

PS: "EntityManagerFactoryUtils" is not doing the same as PersistenceContext ?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do I'd annotate a method in the interface by `@Query("<your native select counting what you need>", native=true)`.

When I need any fancy logic, I usually create a service, which is using the repository like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {

    private final MyRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService (MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public int myMethod(){
        //code using repository
    }

}
```

Comment: tks for your reply, i also tried to use @Query native= true, but here i can't... It's a select from dual. Within the select a dynamic concatanation of a sequence name with a date and day, JPA does not support parameter injection in the select, i tried...

Comment: Maybe you could experiment running an anonymous block for that purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315403/is-it-possible-to-use-oracle-anonymous-block-within-the-query-annotation-of-spr

Comment: I tried it too :) with BEGIN and END on sql developper, it was working perfectly. except   That I was not able to return a value from that. after googling how to return value, I read multiple time, it was not possible.

Comment: As example I was unable to return anything from that inside a @query native true :  
`DECLARE
v_holding VARCHAR2(1000);
v_holding2 VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[select trim(to_char(sysdate, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=english'))||'_BOOKING_SEQ.NEXTVAL' from dual]' INTO v_holding;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || v_holding || ' from dual' INTO v_holding2;
END;` from what I read it's not possible even if it is working in sql developer

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what else to try.